# How to open new tab in same Cypress window when you don't have attributes like target and/or url in the href?

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I am using Cypress 13.5.0 to automate testcases. My testcase is simple to click on link and it will open new tab then perform some actions in new tab.

I know Cypress do not support multi tabs and multi browser windows. I learn the workarounds and implemented as follows:

```
cy.get('MyLocator').invoke('attr', 'href').then(myLink => {
cy.visit(myLink)})

cy.get('MyLocator').should('have.attr', 'href')
.then((href) => {
cy.visit(href)})
```

None of above solution worked because in HTML i dont have a url link in href attribute instead a Javascript function is called in href attribute, following is the HTML code:

```
<td valign="center" style="width: 55%" class="row-white">
<a class="className" href="javascript:launchCourse('parameter')">courseName</a>
</td>
```

could any body help how to deal with that scenario. thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the code behind the javascript function `launchCourse`? Without knowing that, you can't answer the question adequately.

Comment: @Edoardo.Ballerini The code is beyond my approach i request team and they forward me this:
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var launchWindow;
function launchCourse(cId, eId, cType) {
 
 var url = "#springUrl("/l_launchCourse.do")";

 var params = "?cId="+cId+"&eId="+eId+"&method=displayProfile&cType="+cType;
 
 launchWindow = window.open(addUrlParameters(url, params));
 launchWindow.focus();
 launchWindow.opener=this.window;
 }`

Comment: Add that code to the question, we cannot read it properly in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pattern here [Deal with window.open](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowopen) you can use to test this case.

To summarize -

There are a few ways that a window can be opened, one is by `href` as you pointed out. Another is by javascript call to `window.open(addUrlParameters(url, params))`.

Using `cy.stub()` stops the `window.open()` call and allows you to assert that it has been called. It's necessary for regression testing to make sure no bug is introduced in the button click handler.

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
})

cy.get('MyLocator').click()

cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledOnceWithExactly', <url-for-window-open>)
```

You need to know what `<url-for-window-open>` is - easy to find, just click in normal browser and copy the URL after window opens.

To test that new page, start a second test and use `cy.visit()`

```js
it('regression test - new window is opened at <url-for-window-open>', () => {
  cy.visit(<page-with-link>)
  cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
  })
  cy.get('MyLocator').click()
  cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledOnceWithExactly', <url-for-window-open>)
})

it('test page at <url-for-window-open>', () => {
  cy.visit(<url-for-window-open>)
  ... testing this page
})
```

Comment: i am new in cypress after your answer i learn about stubs and understand. issue is resolved. appreciated!.